# How to modify part of a single line in sed

Tags: linux, sed

I have an `installation.sh` file such as:

```
 ... line 1 ...
 ... line 2 ...
 POP3_SERVER_NAME = localhost
 ... line 4 ...
 ...
```

And, I would like to replace the value of `POP3_SERVER_NAME` on line 3 in my file, which might or might not be `localhost` with some other value.

I know how to get at the 3rd line with:

```
sed -n '3p' installation.sh
```

But I need to get only at the `localhost` part.

I want to print the value, and replace the actual value with another value in my `installation.sh` file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to print the value to replace it. In `sed` printing and replacing require different commands:

### To modify the line

The literal answer for your question is:

```
sed -i '3s/POP3_SERVER_NAME = .*/POP3_SERVER_NAME = new_value/' installation.sh
```

Explanation:

- `-i` - edit files in place (makes backup if extension supplied)
- `3` - for the 3rd line
- `s/search/replace/` - search for `search` and replace it with `replace`

But you can probably make it more general by omitting one of the constraints e.g:

```
sed -i 's/POP3_SERVER_NAME = .*/POP3_SERVER_NAME = new_value/' installation.sh
```

or

```
sed -i '3s/= .*$/= new_value/' installation.sh
```

### To print the value

```
sed -n '3s/POP3_SERVER_NAME = //p' installation.sh
```

Differences from line modify:

- `-n` - suppress automatic printing of pattern space
- `p` - print this line.
- replacing the matching string with an empty string.

or

```
sed -n 's/POP3_SERVER_NAME = //p' installation.sh
```

or

```
sed -n '3s/.* = //p' installation.sh
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use awk:

```
awk -F '[ =]+' 'NR==3{print $3}' file
```

Or using sed:

```
sed -n '3s/^.*= *\(.*\)$/\1/p' file
```